# Chrome console error: The requested version (1) is less than the existing version (2)

Tags: google-chrome

The following error shows up in the Chrome console -

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The requested version (1) is less than the existing version (2).
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 9):

Found out what this is.
My local storage indexed DB had a versioned record which was not matching expectation.

> I think I removed all local storage. When the record was written with the updated version of the code everything worked.

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: I think I removed all local storage. When the record was written with the updated version of the code everything worked.

Comment: That did the trick for me too. I had also posted a question, so I updated it with some details:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49984198/firestore-4-10-1-internal-assertion-failed-asyncqueue-is-already-failed-the/49990333#49990333