# FIRESTORE (4.10.1) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: AsyncQueue is already failed: The requested version (1) is less than the existing version (2)

Tags: angular, firebase, angular5, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm sorry for being vague, but I really don't know what to mention except that I am receiving this error!  I have no idea why except that I think it has something to do with version in compatibility.  Everything worked on one machine. I cloned it to another and have this error now.

I'm running Angular 5 with angularfire2.

Please let me know which logs, etc. would be helpful.

Thanks,
Wayne

I am also using ngx-pwa-localStorage so it may have something to with:
[Chrome console error: The requested version (1) is less than the existing version (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34336506/chrome-console-error-the-requested-version-1-is-less-than-the-existing-versio)

below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "scriptertainment",
  "version": "0.4.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.4.6",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "0.0.52",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^5.2.10",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.1.0",
    "@ngx-pwa/local-storage": "^5.2.0",
    "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.6",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^4.12.0",
    "ionicons": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-filter-pipe": "2.1.0",
    "ngx-swiper-wrapper": "^5.3.8",
    "open-iconic": "^1.1.1",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.0.489",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "swiper": "^4.2.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/819775/igor for the assistance.

The answer is to manually delete the firestore IndexDB entries.  In Chrome, enter the Dev Console, go to application tab. Locate IndexDB on the left and expand. For each firebase db in the list, select the db and use the "Delete Database" button.

This was ok for me since my app is not yet in production, but I would have to imagine that for live sites, you'll need to implement a db delete call when the page loads and refresh the page or put in a place a temporary site redirect that handles the db cleanup.

Since the update seems to hose the FB DB, I'm not sure how you would reclaim that data. Hopefully, your app persists the data elsewhere, if it's important.

Comment: Did this become a production issue for you? I found that not enabling offline persistence cleared the error for me, but your point about production sites has me worried.

Comment: I had the same issue with 5.5.0 and this fixed it.

Comment: @wtk, This wasn't a prod concern for me since I didn't go into production until AFTER the site was updated.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when testing two different apps with two different versions of firebase.

The simplest solution I found was to  just clear your browser history.

Answer (score 1):

I removed offline persistence and the error went away.

If you're not sure where that is, search codebase for variations of:

`firebase.firestore().enablePersistence()`

Comment: I tried your solution and it solved my problem, but the main draw of this approach is that it increases the number of firestore readings!

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused when offline persistence is enabled and more than one tab is opened for the specific domain.
Localhost also counts
I find the error misleading though

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the firebase cache setup in the browser cache is incompatible between some firebase versions.  What worked best for me was to use an incognito browser window rather than clearing history.